# Accessing local server-images outside of webapp (tomcat 8)

Tags: apache, jsp, tomcat, servlets, tomcat8

I've seen some posts regarding this, but can somehow not figure it out.
I've got some images stored in, lets say c:\web\images\
I've created a jsp that I want to iterate through, and show all the images in this folder.

The top part is for uploading images to this folder, this works.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Gallery</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="uploadtest" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="file" /> <input type="submit" />
    </form>
            <h1>Gallery</h1>

            <c:forEach items="${bildeliste}" var="i" varStatus="status">
                <img src="images/${i}" width="175px"/>
                <p> ${i} </p>
            </c:forEach>
</body>
</html>
```

The doGet looks like this

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        File directory = new File("/images/");
        File[] list = directory.listFiles();

        request.setAttribute("bildeliste", list);

        request.getRequestDispatcher("WEB-INF/index.jsp").forward(request,
                response);
    }
```

I've read that I need to configure the server.xml file to create a "virtual" pathing, relative to the real pathing, or something like that.

The server.xml file is located in apache/conf/server.xml
http://pastebin.com/nRvAcsMU

And so far what I've understood is that I have to add:

```
<Context docBase="/images/" path="c:/web/images" >
```

But I'm not sure where this is supposed to go, I keep getting errors because I'm wrongly editing this file.

Correct me if I am wrong, also if you have a better way to do this, please tell :)

I'll be around, so just ask if I missed something.